# can't import seaborn on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have installed numpy, pandas and matplot lib
but installation of seaorn i not possible. I ve tried updating Numpy, installing seaborn through the cmd command but in vain. I restarted the kernel each time.

```
import seaborn as sns
```

I keep  recieving ;

```
 ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _arpack: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have used:

```
!pip install seaborn
pip install numpy --upgrade --user
pip import seaborn as sns df = sns.load_dataset(penguins) sns.pairplot(df, hue=species)
```

Comment: have you tried using conda?

Comment: I am using conda yes

Comment: `arpack` means some C/C++ library for math calculations. Maybe you have to install it manually.

Comment: I see you got this sorted, however since you attempted an exclamation point with `pip`, I'll add  that when running `pip` or `conda` inside a notebook, avoid the exclamation point as it can cause environment issues and use the `%pip` or `%conda` magic commands added recently that insure installations go to the environment backing the notebook. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more information about those modern magic commands.

Comment: thank you so much @Wyane, wll definitely use this trick.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your seaborn and/or numpy installation is broken or at least there is some version conflict.

Try to run these command from the command line :

1. `pip uninstall seaborn numpy`
2. `pip install mkl numpy seaborn`

After that, you can run this code in your Jupyter notebook:

```
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.pairplot(df, hue="species")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the problem was fixed by updating matplotlib on the conda shell.

```
conda update matplotlib
```